# I have no personal projects, should I mention school projects in my cover letter?

Tags: cv, application-cover-letter, projects

In my current studies I have been tasked with so many projects that I cannot find the time to work on personal projects.

Should I mention my school projects in my cover letter / resume ?

Comment: What are you applying to?

Comment: graduate school, sorry i should have mentioned that